# Webdriver IO API test passes even though request is not executed

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, webdriver-io

I've initialised a basic WDIO project using mocha framework.

I have a class below

```
const axios =  require('axios');
class Joke{
    async getJoke(){
        const response = axios.get('https://api.chucknorris.io/jokes/random');
        return response;
    }
 }
module.exports = new Joke();
```

This is my spec file:

```
const Joke = require("./Joke");

describe("GET random jokes", () => {
  it("responds with json", async () => {
    const res = browser.call(async() => await Joke.getJoke());
    console.log(res);
  });
});
```

The console shows that my test has passed however there's no output of the response. Been trying to crack my head at this, could anyone point out what the issue is?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Aren't you missing an `await` here before browser.call?

```js
const res = **await** browser.call(async() => await Joke.getJoke());
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Webdriver in sync mode, there is no need to await `browser.call` as suggested in the previous comment, since `browser.call` is used to wrap async code to perform like sync code. However, the await is missing when calling `axios.get`.

```
const response = await axios.get('https://api.chucknorris.io/jokes/random');
```